# Iterating through col but not through row

Tags: c++

I'm quite confused, apologize in advance if this is a kinda stupid question.
But uh, it iterates through `col` but it *seems* to not iterate through `row`.

`MAX_BLOCKS` = 9

`maxtrix` is: `int matrix[9][9] = {{0}};`

```
int iterateRow{0};
int iterateCol{0};
int currentMaxRow{2};
int currentMaxCol{2};

for(int nineBlockIterator {0}; nineBlockIterator<MAX_BLOCKS; nineBlockIterator++)
{
    int sum {0};
    for( ; iterateRow <= currentMaxRow; iterateRow++)
    {
        for( ; iterateCol <= currentMaxCol; iterateCol++ )
        {
                std::cout << this->matrix[iterateRow][iterateCol] << std::endl;

                sum += this->matrix[iterateRow][iterateCol];
        }
    }
```

I think it would be difficult to understand/explain this question without the inputs. But basically what's happening is that it seems that `iterateCol` is iterating through `0,1,2` but `iterateRow` isn't iterating at all.

Full code with inputs here:

http://ideone.com/T6pfLB

Comment: You may want to reset the value of `iterateCol` (and `iterateRow`)  when the inner loops start.

Comment: DUH, haha....wow can't believe it